# UITableView loading same images when scrolling (Parse.com SDK)

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

**Scenario**

I have an app where I display data to user in a PFQueryTableViewController. I have everything working exactly as it should with the exception to the images. When I reuse a cell that has already loaded in an image, That image tends to stay on the cell next time it is dequeued for in cellForRowAtIndexPath. And when Im scrolling sometimes they change when I scroll back up to look at them again.

**Code I'm using to populate my image**

```
-(PFTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

        PFFile *imgFile = object[@"picture"];
        cell.picture.file = imgFile;

        [cell.picture loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

            if (!error) {

                [indexArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

                [UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{

                    cell.picture.alpha = 1.0;
                    [cell.indicator setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
                    [cell.indicator stopAnimating];

                }];

            }

        }];

}
```

**Question**

Does anyone know how to load an image and keep that image on that cell for that index and only that index and keep it there?

Comment: use egoimageview it will manage cache as well as background data download.

Comment: // Create an EGOImageView
    EGOImageView * egoImageView = [[EGOImageView alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    egoImageView.tag = EGO_Image;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:egoImageView];
    [egoImageView release];